# Does combining composition with association still follow the rules of OOP?

Tags: oop, architecture, uml, software-design, class-design

When it comes to class diagrams, can an association or aggregation exist between two objects that are in composition with one base object?

Example:
Class `Car` has a composition relation with class `Engine` and class `Fueltank`. So `Car` has An `Engine` and a `Fueltank`, and `Engine` and a `Fueltank` are dependent on `Car`. But `Engine` also needs information from `Fueltank`, without intervention of `Car` (in accordance with a sequence diagram for example). That means `Engine` and `Fueltank` also have a relationship although, they're both compositions of the `Car`. See diagram below:

[image]

So, the question is, may such “loops”, or better redudant associations, in class diagrams occur? Or does that undermine the rules of OOP?

Comment: where is the "loop" in your car example?

Comment: Not sure your analogy really works.  I for one would not attribute a relationship between the fuel tank and the engine except for the car object that is holding them both.

Comment: The word 'loop' may not be the best in use here, but there is like a closed circle to say so. The question is if that's a problem?

Comment: @NathanOliver When different objects are involved in some kind of a chronologic proces, but those objects are direct related to one base object, class A in my example, then how could I implement it? Because when I add no relationsip between a class B and C, although they're involved in a proces, information would go back and forth via class A. But that could be unfortunate.

Comment: That is no loop and it's not forbidden. Still, why do you see an issue?

Comment: I’ve shortened the question by removing the introductory sentences, and by merging the abstract and concrete examples to avoid redundancy. With “loop” you mean “circular dependency” or redundant associations ?

Comment: I vote to reopen the question: it shows personal research, is a founded question, and the only ambiguity is the unappropriate use of the term “loop”, which is a minor issue that does not prevent an objective, factual answer.

Comment: @Christophe Thank u very much for the vote and editing. With "loop" I indeed meant more like redundant associations. Am I right designing my software with such a principle.

Comment: @R.H.dev I hope the question gets reopened. Indeed, this design is perfectly legit, but it has a couple of drawbacks (ambiguity and design)

Answer (score 1):

### This is legal UML...

This kind of combination of composition and association is perfectly legal in UML and does not undermine OOP. There are only a few constraints in UML in this regard:

- > Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite
  > object at a time.
- > Compositions may be linked in a directed acyclic graph with transitive deletion characteristics;
- > An end Property of an Association may only be marked as a shared or composite aggregation if the Association is binary and the other end is not marked as a shared or composite aggregation.

The first two restrictions are at object level and not necessarily at the class. The last restriction is for the class diagram:  it says that a same association can't have composite or shared aggregation at both end. None of those restrictions are relevant for your diagram.

### ... but may not express what you think

The problem is that this diagram does not express what you think.  It says that a `Car c` is composed of an `Engine e` and a `Fueltank f`; it also says that `e` is aggregated with a Fueltank, which could be f by coincidence, but which could also be another `Fueltank` and even a `Fueltank` of another `Car`.  The model does not well represent the triangular relationship between the classes. Here some hints:

- You may prevent the inconsistencies by adding some constraints that the engine fuel tank is the same than the car fuel tank.
- You may make the engine/fueltank relation a derived association (i.e. somehow the engine's fuel tank will be derived from the car's fuel tank.
- You may make the car/fueltank relation a derived association (i.e. the car's fuel tank is derived from its engine).
- you ignore the relationship engine/fueltank and instead, use the car as a mediator between its components.

Comment: Can you show me an example how a better diagram in this situation would look like?

Comment: @R.H.dev the derived associations are shown with the association name precded by a / (you must of course add the operations that allow to derive the association (e.g. gettank() in a car that can use gettank() of the engine. For the mediator design pattern, you can find it on wikipedia.